# mouse stops working

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm using a Logitech Maraton M705, but recently its acting strange, but only on my laptop and not on my workstation..

I have had the mouse for over a year but never experienced problems before..

Some times (quite often) the mouse stops working and I get a message about Windows can't recognize the USB device.. If I plug it into another USB port it works again for a couple of minutes..

I have also tried format C:\, but the problem persists! Now Windows isn't even prompting me about it not recognizing the mouse.. it just stops working

Comment: I have sent it to Logitech but they throw it back..

Comment: Do you have SetPoint set to auto-update? It seems the last update has caused problems for many users.

Comment: yes, got the latest.. my problem started 2-3 months ago

Answer (score 0):

If it only happens on the one computer, and you've tried a clean installation of Windows, then it's either something with the physical hardware, or it's another piece of software you're installing that is conflicting with the mouse somehow.

If you really want to find the culprit, you'll want to start with a clean installation of Windows, and don't install anything except Windows updates. Really, not even things like Chrome or IM programs. Use the mouse for a while until either the problem happens again, or you're confident it isn't going to happen. If the problem happens again, then most likely there is something wrong with either the USB controller or some other part of the motherboard on the laptop.

If the problem does not reoccur, then start installing your normal applications one at a time. After you install each program, use the mouse until the problem occurs, or you're confident it isn't going to happen.

Once you see the problem happen, you'll know which application is causing the conflict.